# WP-Stateless: Multi Regional Vs Regional Storage

Tags: cdn, google, cloudflare

if I upload all wp-content/uploads to google cloud storage and serve from there directly(stateless), is there any point to create multi regional google cloud storage? Other than increasing unnecessary cost?

My understanding:
My nginx+php+wordpress webserver is in US-West1. Then, wp-stateless (stateless mode) will store in X region.

???> No matter where the web visitors are, it will always be a US-West1 server requesting image/object from X region?

So, it would make sense to only make X regions = US-West1 and no need multi region? +same region = less transfer cost

Is my understanding correct? Can anyone please clarify?

Thank you